# button won't show up when I hover over an element

Tags: css, next.js

so I am trying to show a button when I hover over an element but I want it to move from bottom to up just a bit  (the code is in nextjs)
I am using an api and in the product block I wanna have a button that says add to cart but I want it to show up when I hover over the product the image has an animation that makes it a little bigger when you hover over it so I wanna keep that but then show the button as well doing the moving up a little animation

```
function shop({ products }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/shop">Shop</Link>
      </nav>
      <div className="title1">
        <h1>Explore All Products</h1>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div key={product.id} className="product">
              <Link href="">
                <img src={product.image} className="product-img"></img>
                <h2 className="product-title">{product.title.substring(0, 11)}</h2>
                <h3 className="product-price">${product.price}</h3>
                <button className="btn">Add to Cart</button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my css

```
      .btn{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -140px;
  right: -190px;
  background-color: #ff497c;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 0px;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
 
}



.product:hover .btn {
  display: block;
  transform: translate3d(20px, 20px, 0px);
}

.btn:hover{
  transform: translateY(-10px);

}
```

Comment: Remove the `+` from `.product:hover + .btn`

Comment: There is no such thing as `</br>`. [The br element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)